# Proper SE site to ask about personal medical problem

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know I can not ask the below question on the medical Stack Exchange site, but is there any other place to ask it on the network, like **chat** or another stack?

The question is:

> My mother has had a [mastectomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastectomy) (breast cancer tumor removing) around two weeks ago and. After surgery I heard from her doctor that she would have to remove the drain after 5 day after the surgery, and now at the place of surgery she has [seroma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seroma).
>
> So, my mother had a brain stroke 10 years ago and after that is sitting in a wheelchair and doesn't make any movement and excesses, she also doesn't do the post-apocalyptic exercise described [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.cancer.org/cancer/breast-cancer/treatment/surgery-for-breast-cancer/exercises-after-breast-cancer-surgery.html).
>
> Also after the surgery, she moved to another town and went to another breast surgeon, who he said the seroma was present because of the drain was removed too soon, so I will contact the persons in charge of the first surgery, tell them about this situation and ask whether I heard the instruction wrongly (removing drain after 5 days of surgery), but I would like to know others' professional comments about the seroma reason in this situation.

Answer (score 15):

No SE site is appropriate for personal medical problems. They are explicitly off-topic at both [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [MedicalSciences.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Do not ask in chat or anywhere else to try to circumvent these restrictions, and do not listen to any advice you get through these venues unless that advice is "ask your doctor".

Unlike a commenter, I would not recommend asking medical questions to anyone on the internet with the exception of web portals from your health care provider that give you access to true doctors and nurses licensed to care for you.

Comment: We have one problem in my country (Iran) the government add some unqualified student to the magical university as some rents which could be almost 40% of the capacity of universities in specialized fields of medicine, so there is some spychlogical reason that we cannot trust each other as many other countries do, so I tried to ask this question.

Comment: @sosa sa: Re *"mefucal university"* and *"magical university"*. Don't you mean *"[medical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/medical#Adjective) university"* (the first could be the result of a double typo)?

Answer (score 13):

This is the sort of question you need to ask of a medical professional, locally, or reach out to a reputable company specifically licensed to provide medical assistance long-distance. If your current physician can't help you, you need to find a second person who will talk to you.

I'm sorry but this sort of personal medical advice is something that we can not allow here for a variety of reasons including that it is an invasion of privacy to have this sort of information on our sites, permanently, and there is legal risk - if someone tells you the wrong thing, that could cause additional harm or death.

These are things we are not set up to handle, so we set a hard limit on them - it is out of scope for our network.

I wish you and your mother well and hope you're able to find some help locally to solve your problem.